# Node.js | loop over an array , make post calls and accumulate result in an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, coffeescript

I wish to make a call in Node.js somethine like this (i m using coffeescript for node.js)

```
test = [] //initially an empty array
list = []//an array with 10 json object

for li in list
  get_data url , li, (err,data) -> test.push data
```

**my get_data method look like**

```
get_data: (url, json_data, callback) ->
  throw "JSON obj is required" unless _.isObject(json_data) 
  post_callback = (error, response) ->
    if error
      callback(error)
    else
      callback(undefined, response)
    return
  request.post {url: url, json: json_data}, post_callback
  return
```

**problem is I am not able to collect the result from request.post into the 'test' array**
I Know I am doing something wrong in the for loop but not sure what

Comment: `(err,data) -> test` just returns `test`, it doesn't add anything

Comment: What are you expecting `test << data` to do?

Comment: @muistooshort Perhaps he meant to write `test.push data`? Not sure.

Comment: sorry , I mean test.push(data)

Comment: The equivalent JavaScript is `get_data(url, li, function(err, data) {return test.push(data);});` - is that what you expected?

Comment: @merbs yes ......
If i dont loop it and call 
    get_data url , json, (err,data) -> console.log(data);

i get back the value but when I loop it and want to accumulate the response in the array i cannot

Comment: did you intend to have `post_callback(err,data)`? Oh, ... hmm, maybe its a scoping issue...

Comment: I am missing something in the logic:(

Comment: try this: put `test = []` inside the callback, and then `alert test`; my current hypothesis is that test doesn't even exist from where you're calling it (which isn't immediately obvious to me). When is the `post_callback` called?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18210/discussion-between-merbs-and-rockyboy-ruby)

Comment: is there an error thrown? the code as it is silently drops the error. So maybe the calls never succeed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't appear to have any way of knowing when all of the requests have returned.  You should really consider using [a good async library](https://github.com/caolan/async), but here's how you can do it:

```
test = [] //initially an empty array
list = []//an array with 10 json object

on_complete = ->
  //here, test should be full
  console.log test
  return

remaining = list.length
for li in list
  get_data url , li, (err,data) ->
    remaining--
    test.push data
    if remaining == 0
      on_complete()
```

Comment: I used **steps.js** to get the response from request.post and accumulated it in the array. Thanks aaron for the direction

Answer (score 0):

In just looking at your code (not trying it out), the problem seems to be a matter of "when you'll get the response" rather than a matter of "if you'll get the response". After your for loop runs, all you have done is queue a bunch of requests. You need to either design it so the request for the second one doesn't occur until the first has responded OR (better) you need a way to accumulate the responses and know when all of the responses have come back (or timed out) and then use a different callback to return control to the main part of your program.

BTW, [here](http://svn.maccherone.com/urlmultiloader/trunk/src/com/maccherone/urlmultiloader/URLMultiLoader.as) is code for a multi-file loader that I created for ActionScript. Since I/O is asynchronous in ActionScript also, it implements the accumulating approach I describe above. It uses events rather than callbacks but it might give you some ideas on how to implement this for CoffeeScript.